# Admin shows doubled labels

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, vichuploaderbundle

I'm trying to display an admin create form which uses an image upload (vich) but the labels appear to be doubled. What configurations am I missing here?

```
$formMapper
    ->add('color', null, array('label' => 'label.color'))
    ->add('image',
        'sonata_type_admin');
```

My other admin that I'm using here looks like :

```
 $formMapper
      ->add('imageFile', 'vich_image', array());
```

My `config.yml` has

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'VichUploaderBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

I've tried using `sonata_type_collection` instead of `sonata_type_admin` but I'm receiving `INVALID MODE : s56b1f065bd50c_image - type : sonata_type_collection - mapping : 1` instead of any button being displayed there

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

A fix has been made in the beginning of last year : https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/issues/369

Not stable tag has been made since this fix, i think you should use the latest beta version or you can create your own form type that extend the vich upload file type to remove one of the two labels